# How to capture dynamic value in regular expression which depend on another dynamic value

Tags: regex, jmeter

[image]I am new to Jmeter and I am looking for a way of capturing bolded "id" ("id":"56fa091ae4b081fb934b083a") which is having a dynamic data based on the "parentEventId" which is also a dynamic value in metadata section (I already have the "parentEventId" value taken from previous thread group). There can be multiple records with different "parentEventId"s and I need to get the mentioned "id" data of a selected "parentEventId".

This might have a simple answer but I couldn't find expression to use in If Controller and I have tried several RegEx extractors none of them worked and I couldn't find any positive answer for my question in web as well.
So any help on this would be highly appreciated, Thank you in advance

Below is my Body Data;

[{**"id":"56fa091ae4b081fb934b083a"**,"eventCalendar":{"id":"53757a6c156695a10bcefd57","type":"PERSON","displayName":"Test Name"},"organizerEvent":true,"start":1459486061505,"end":1459489661505,"allDay":false,"title":"test title","description":"test description","location":"test location","className":"cs-12","type":"CALENDAR","visibleToPublic":false,"metadata":{"parentEventId":"56fa091ae4b081fb934b0839"},

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: Attached the screenshots, what I have tried was so simple.

Answer (score 2):

If your `parentEventId` and `id` are equal - why just not to use `parentEventId`? If not - update your question with full response and show relationships.

By the way, it's better to us [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project for working with JSON Data, it's much more handy than regular expressions. For instance, you can extract `parentEventId` with something like:

```
$..parentEventId[0]
```

References:

- [JSON Path - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to **Parsing JSON**)

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly you are supplied with a dynamic `parentEventId` information and you would like to extract the child id from JSON data accordingly. If this is the case the following might be your solution

```
var parentEventId = "56fa091ae4b081fb934b0839",
             data = '[{"id":"56fa091ae4b081fb934b083a","eventCalendar":{"id":"53757a6c156695a10bcefd57","type":"PERSON","displayName":"Test Name"},"organizerEvent":true,"start":1459486061505,"end":1459489661505,"allDay":false,"title":"test title","description":"test 56fa091ae4b081fb934b083adescription","location":"test location","className":"cs-12","type":"CALENDAR","visibleToPublic":false,"metadata":{"parentEventId":"56fa091ae4b081fb934b0839"},',
              rex = new RegExp('\\[{"id":"([a-f0-9]{24})"(?=.*{"parentEventId":"' + parentEventId + '"})',"g"),
              res = rex.exec(data);
console.log(res[1]); // 56fa091ae4b081fb934b083a
```

Comment: Yes @Redu you have got my question correctly, really sorry I'm not sure where should I use this solution, so far I have only used RegEx. So should this enter as Beanshell PostProcessor or what?

Comment: Sorry @Thimz i am not experienced with Jmeter at all. But may be this blog post on Jmeter regex can help you: https://blog.flood.io/guide-to-jmeter-regular-expressions/

Comment: Yeah @Redu I have already checked that blog post but that couldn't help me I tried some regular expressions and got an answer for my problem, that is;

"id":"([^"]+)"(?:.)*"parentEventId":"56fe3409e4b01e5b9661d878"

the 'parentEventID' which I have previously captured is in a separate thread group variable and now I'm struggling to give that variable value to the above. Highly appreciate if you can help on this :)

BeanshellPostProcessor used
{__setProperty(parentEventID,${parentEventID})}

edit RegEx as
,{"id":"([^"]+)"(?:.)*"parentEventId":"{__Property(parentEventID)}"

But that didn't work